# Is it true that for any two events $A$ and $B$, $P(A)$ equals $0$ only if $P(A|B)$ is also $0$?

Tags: probability

I know that the reverse is true, as $P(A|B) = (P(A)*P(B))/(P(B))$, so it holds that if $P(A)$ is $0$, then $P(A|B)$ must also be $0$, but can this statement be true?

Comment: Are you assuming $\mathbb{P}(B) \neq 0$? I.e., how do you define  $\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)$ when $\mathbb{P}(B)=0$? (otherwise, playing on that you could take $A=B$... $\mathbb{P}(A\mid A)$ is a sneaky thing when $\mathbb{P}(A)= 0$.)

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking, regardless of the value of $B$, if there are any instances where $P(A)$ can equal $0$ without $P(A|B)$ having a value of $0$.

Comment: And again, **how** do you define the conditional expectation when $B$ has probability 0?

Comment: In general, saying *"if X is true then Y is true"* is equivalent to saying *"X is true only if Y is true"*, as both are the same as *"Y is true if X is true"*.  But you may not actually know what you state

Comment: @AugusteBaudin  You cannot ask a question about properties of things that are not even defined in the first place... see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event) (re the Borel–Kolmogorov paradox).

Comment: Your statement is wrong, but if $P(B) \not = 0$ you can know $\displaystyle P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A)P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$

Comment: No, it is not. $P(B^c\mid B)=0$ for all $B$ including $P(B^c)>0$. It's also not true that $P(A)=0$ implies $P(A|B)=0$ (unless you requires $P(B)>0$) since $P(A|A)=1$ for any non-empty $A$ including $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @A.S. Just to be perfectly clear with regard to the comment "thread," the "No, it is not" refers to the OP's question, *not* to the preceding comment.

Comment: @Clem While conditioning on sets of measure zero is indeed tricky, $P(B|A)=1$ for $A\subseteq B$ is not tricky at all (and requires no advanced probability/conditional expectation at all). Similarly $P(B|A)=0$ for $A\subseteq B^c$.

Comment: I can believe (and live with) that, but the minimum required to answer the OP's question is that (s)he explain how that question handles sets with probability zero. Even the well-defined cases you mention require more than the degree zero of thought about them shown in the question.

Comment: @A.S. , just curious:  Under what definition of conditional probability are you concluding that $P[A|A]=1$ for cases $P[A]=0$? I would just say that such a thing is not defined (under a standard definition).

Comment: @Mic Under any reasonable definition - incl. the standard one. $P(A|A)=1$ is determined way before ratio analysis of conditional probabilities comes into play and isn't even in the realm of probabilistic reasoning. Since $A\Rightarrow A$, if $A$ is true then $A$ is true (always - not just a.s.). Why this is is omitted in the standard presentation (while still (erroneously) extending definition of independence to all sets of measure $0$ and $1$ which leads to such absurdities as a set being independent of itself) is beyond me and underscores how unnatural standard (Kolmogorov's) presentation is

Comment: For example, if you (heuristically) define $P[B|A]$ for cases $P[A]=0$ via a limit over some events $A_n$ such that for all $n$ we have $A \subseteq A_n$, $P[A_n]>0$, $P[A_n]\rightarrow 0$, then you get: $P[B|A] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{P[B \cap A_n]}{P[A_n]}$.  But if $B=A$, this would give a limiting value of $0$, not 1, over any such $A_n$ events. Of course the real difficulty is not knowing _which_ $A_n$ sets to pick for this "definition."

Comment: @Mic Ratio analysis of conditional probabilities is *defining* conditional probability as a ratio: $P(B\mid A)=P(A,B)/P(A)$. It's not the only way to capture (intuitive) notion of conditional probability and there're approaches to probability that take conditional probability as a basic building block. If you need a definition, define $P(A|A)=1$ for all non-empty $A$ and make everything else respects this. If you want to dive deeper, take a look at http://philrsss.anu.edu.au/people-defaults/alanh/papers/what_cp_couldnt_be.pdf // The limiting heuristic doesn't apply when $P(B)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I take it that you really mean:  Under standard definitions, $P[B|A]$ is not defined if $P[A]=0$.  Intuitively, it could be defined to be 1 in the special case $B \supseteq A$, and the link provides some nonstandard argumentation to make this more formal.

Comment: @Mic Yes. The real question is: how can one disagree that $P(A\mid A)=1$? It's like saying you can't subtract a larger number from the smaller because it's $\notin N$ //I'm of the "objects should capture intuition" slant, so I'm strongly against extending definition of independence to all sets of measure $0$ and $1$ (which makes these sets independent of every other set) - apart from $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ - these sets are indeed independent from everything else. So the standard approach sins twice re: $P(A)=0$- through commission (independence) and omission (conditional probabilities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing $P(A) = 0 \implies P(A | B) = 0:$
Assume $P(A) = 0,$ and as mentioned above,
$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0}{P(B)} = 0.$$
The converse is not necessarily true. As an example, let
$$\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\},$$
with $\frac{1}{4}$ probability assigned to each sample point. Let
$$A = \{1,2\}$$
and
$$B = \{3,4\},$$
We can see that
$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(\emptyset)}{P(B)}
= \
frac{0}{P(B)} = 0$$
but
$P(A) = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}.$